# trigger to update a Total_count column in one table by adding count/quantity in another table

Tags: oracle, triggers

I created an inventory table with columns `product_id` and `total_count`.  When a purchase is entered in purchase table(`purchase_id`, `supplier_id`, `product_id`,`price, quantity`), it should update the total_count in inventory table.  The default value for total_count in inventory table is 0.

for example when a purchase is made (supplier, charger ,price,25) it should update the inventory ( Charger, 25).

I am not being able to do that. here's my code:

```
create or replace trigger trg_update_inventory 
after insert on supplier_product 
for each row 
begin
    update inventory set total_count=total_count+ quantity where .....
```

I am stuck at this point. how do I make the trigger get the quantity from the purchase table and update the total balance?

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_update_inventory
  AFTER INSERT ON supplier_product
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE inventory
     SET total_count = total_count + :new.quantity
   WHERE product_id  = :new.product_id
END;
```

should work.  From a system architecture standpoint, however, you would be much better off having a stored procedure `make_purchase` that does both the `INSERT` into the `PURCHASE` table and the `UPDATE` to the `INVENTORY` table rather than putting that sort of logic in a trigger.